# Keras accuracy not increasing

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to perform sentiment classification using Keras. I am trying to do this using a basic neural network (no RNN or other more complex type). However when I run the script I see no increase in accuracy during training/evaluation. I am guessing I am setting up the output layer incorrectly but I am not sure of that. `y_train` is a list `[1,2,3,1,2,4,5]` (5 different labels) containing the targets belonging to the features in `X_train_seq_padded`. The setup is as follows:

```
padding_len = 24 # len of each tokenized sentence
neurons = 16 # 2/3 the length of the text that is padded
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(neurons, input_dim = padding_len, activation = 'relu', name = 'hidden-1'))
model.add(Dense(neurons, activation = 'relu', name = 'hidden-2'))
model.add(Dense(neurons, activation = 'relu', name = 'hidden-3'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid', name = 'output_layer'))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor = 'accuracy', patience = 5, mode = 'max')]
history = model.fit(X_train_seq_padded, y_train, epochs = 100, batch_size = 64, callbacks = callbacks)
```

Comment: loss should be `binary_crossentropy`.

Comment: @M.Innat also in the case that I have 5 possible classes?

Comment: or, the last layer should be `(5, activation='softmax'`)

Comment: @M.Innat changing to binary_crossentropy did something (now calculates loss) however I still see no model improvements. I stick at 0.0378. Adding your second suggenstion results in an error ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 5) vs (None, 1)).

Comment: If your labels are integer and not on-hot encoded, then use `tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits= True)`

Comment: @M.Innat Should the `from_logits` parameter be `False` as we apply `sigmoid` activation in the last layer ? We only specify `from_logits=True` when not using any activation in the last layer right ?

Comment: If your labels are one-hot encoded then `from_logits` should be `False`. If integer labels, then `True`.

Comment: @M.Innat could you post your reply as an answer? I am getting some strange results now but I am getting something. No matter if I add/remove layers, change amount of neurons, change the activation function, change the input dim, I keep getting an accuray of around 0.67... which is reached at around 2 training epochs. But I will post a new question for that.

Comment: @M.Innat No, you are completely incorrect in this last statement, from_logits does not have anything to do with integer or one-hot encoded labels.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I didn't say from_logits doesn't have anything to do with integer..! What I meant is if `y_true` is one-hot encoded labels, then we set `from_logit` to 'False`. Please see my given answer, if these statements are wrong, please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in your above set up if you choose `sigmoid` in your last layer activation function which generally uses for binary classification or multi-label classification then, the loss function should be `binary_crossentropy`.

But if your labels are represented **multi-class** and transformed into **one-hot** encoded then your last layer should be `Dense(num_classes, activations='softmax')` and the loss function would be `categorical_crossentropy`.

But if you don't transform your **multi-class** label but **integer** then your last layer and loss function should be

```
Dense(num_classes)  # with logits 
SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits= True)
```

Or, (**@Frightera**)

```
Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax') # with probabilities 
SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
```

Comment: I  couldn't reproduce your training logs behavior but let me know if it helps.

Comment: You should not set from_logits to true in the loss, it has no relation with integer labels.

Comment: Would you please check [this](https://keras.io/examples/keras_recipes/antirectifier/) example, where `y_true` are integers and the author uses `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits= True)` but not `False`.

Comment: This has fixed the main issue but I am getting strange results. I opened up a new topic for that which can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67397995/strange-results-from-a-neural-network-build-using-keras hope you can take a look at it.

Comment: @M.Innat You should use `from_logits = True` if last layer is linear. When you set it to true AFAIK it calls [softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits). It is not something about labels; being integer or not. You can use one-hot encoded labels and from_logits = True.

Comment: Yes, if you set from_logits to False, it still works with integer labels, but expects logits instead of probabilities.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy in that example code, setting from_logits to False did run the program but it didn't converge at all.

Comment: @M.Innat It converged for me, at epoch 4 loss was around 0.10

Comment: @Frightera have you just changed `from_logits=False` and got the 0.10 training loss?

Comment: @M.Innat I also added `softmax` to the last dense layer. It was the training loss yes.

Comment: @Frightera I see. Sorry, my bad. you're right. Thank you :)