# Strange results from a neural network build using Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I build an sentiment classifier using Keras to predict if a sentence has a sentiment score of 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5. However I am getting some strange results. I will first show my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# the data only reflects the structure of the actual data
# the real data has way larger text and more entries
X_train = ['i am glad i heard about that', 'that is one ugly bike']
y_train = pd.Series(np.array([1, 4])) # pandas series
X_test = ['that hurted me']
y_test = pd.Series(np.array([1, 4])) # pandas series

# tokenizing
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = 5)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_train)
X_train_seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_train)
X_test_seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_test)

# performing some padding
padding_len = 4
X_train_seq_padded = pad_sequences(X_train_seq, maxlen = padding_len)
X_test_seq_padded = pad_sequences(X_test_seq, maxlen = padding_len)

# building the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, input_dim = padding_len, activation = 'relu', name = 'hidden-1'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation = 'relu', name = 'hidden-2'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation = 'relu', name = 'hidden-3'))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax', name = 'output_layer'))

# compiling the model
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# training the model
callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor = 'accuracy', patience = 5, mode = 'max')]
my_model = model.fit(X_train_seq_padded, to_categorical(y_train), epochs = 100, batch_size = 1000, callbacks = callbacks, validation_data = (X_test, to_categorical(y_test)))
```

Using the actual data I keep getting results around 0.67xx (xx random numbers) which are reached after 1/2 epochs, no matter what changes to the code I introduce (and some are extreme).

- I tried changing the padding to 1, 10, 100, 1000.
- I tried removing the layer hidden-2 and hidden-3.
- I tried adding stop word removal before tokenizing.
- I tried using the tahn activation function in the hidden layers.
- I used the sgd optimizer.

Example output of one setup:
[image]

Now my question is, is there something wrong with my code or are these actual possible results?

Comment: The above code is not reproducible. Can you provide exact reproducible code? That would be better to look into.

Comment: @M.Innat I see I made a typo. The code still will not run for some reason. I printed out the types of the data and for X this should be `<class 'list'>` and for y `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`.

Comment: You set `padding_len = 4` and in the pad sequences function you say `maxlen = 4`. You are not padding but truncating the sentences actually.

Comment: Scale the input e.g. this way: X_train_seq_padded=X_train_seq_padded/np.max(X_train_seq_padded) ... to obtain better scale for the data, to get better training result.